# Function error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

please help. I am a begginner at c# but have programed in python before. My problem is that the their is an error which says, Severity  'Program.Sqrt(int)': not all code paths return a value. Please help, i have include a return value and have used an if and else statement.

```
using System;

namespace helloworld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }


        float Sqrt(int x)

        {


            Console.WriteLine("please enter your number to be square rooted");
            string l = Console.ReadLine();
            x = Convert.ToInt32(l);

            float num = 1;
            if (num * num != x)
            {
                num++;
            }
            if (num * num == x)
            {

                return num;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAILED TO EXECUTE");

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `else` branch does not `return` anything, hence the error

Comment: Note that the "basic" tag is for the language BASIC, not basic questions.

Comment: I assume you are doing this for training purposes but be aware there is a Sqrt method in the Math class in the .NET Framework which will do this for you

Comment: A further pointer not related to your question but once you have this compiling it still won't do what you want. I suspect you want to do the `num++` in a loop so it will keep adding to num until it finds the right number. As it stands you will check if num*num is not equal and increment num. You will then check if the new num is correct. If it isn't then you don't try to increment it again so you will only ever get the result if num=1 or num=2 (ie l = 1 or 4). You probably want to look at while loops.

Answer (score 1):

So this is kinda just C# Basics - well.. programming basics...
If you declare your method as a 'type' of return value other than void, then it expects you to use the keyword 'return' at some stage.

You have created a method called:

```
float Sqrt(int x)
```

This indicates that it MUST return a float value.

I can see that in some cases (if statements) you are doing a

```
return num;
```

But look carefully. in the other if statements, there is no return statement - so basically, in the else statement it will get stuck.

In order to make sure that your method does not get stuck - you should make sure that it has the possibility of returning either a valid value, or it throws an exception.

```
if (num * num == x)
            {

                return num;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to execute");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of the compiler error you are receiving is that a method with a declared return type must always return a value of that type, or throw an error.

Let's take a look:

```
float Sqrt(int x)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

What we've just done is declared a method called `Sqrt` that accepts a single `int` parameter called `x`. By using the `float` type at the beginning of the method, we're stating that this method always returns a float.

In your method body, you must return a float or throw an error. Let's take a look at a simple case.

```
float Sqrt(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        // Calculate square root
        return Math.Sqrt(x);
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore imaginary numbers for now, use absolute value
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x));
    }
}
```

The above code works because both the `if` and `else` return a valid value. Your code is failing because your else doesn't return anything; see this simplified example:

```
float Sqrt(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        // Calculate square root
        return Math.Sqrt(x);
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore imaginary numbers for now, use absolute value
        Console.WriteLine("Don't do that!");
        // Note there is no return statement here
    }
}
```

The above example fails, because the `else` doesn't return anything nor does it throw an exception. Another way to hand this is to throw an appropriate exception:

```
float Sqrt(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        // Calculate square root
        return Math.Sqrt(x);
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore imaginary numbers for now, use absolute value
        throw new System.ArgumentException("x must be greater than 0");
    }
}
```

The above example them assumes your code knows how to handle an exception. In the `if else` section, you can perform your logic but you have to return a `float` value or `throw` an exception of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly stated, not all code paths return a value, and this will throw an exception.

```
if (num * num == x)
{

    return num; //Okay
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("FAILED TO EXECUTE");
    //returns nothing here
}
```

To fix this, simply add a `return` statement after your `Console.WriteLine` returning what you'd want if the previous condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

.NET compiler expects return statement in all possible scenarios of a function. If code fails that, it returns compilation error.

You could either return some error OR non-possible value in else block. Since in your code, else is not returning any value/exception, it gives an error.