# MCS: error CS0161: not all code paths return a value

Tags: mono, computer-science

I created simple C# app, and this error appeared after compilation using MCS tried:
`src/Program.cs(6,24): error CS0161: 'Interpreter.runCommand(string)': not all code paths return value`
What the problem tells? Why it appears?
The code:

```cs
using System;

public static class Interpreter
{
    public static string command;
    public static bool runCommand(string __command)
    {
        if (__command == "help")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Available commands:");
            Console.WriteLine("help - displays this menu");
            Console.WriteLine("quit | exit - exits");
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File Manager, Type 'quit' to exit.");
        do
        {
            Console.Write("FM > ");
            Interpreter.command = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!Interpreter.runCommand(Interpreter.command))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not valid FM command. Type 'help' to get help.", Interpreter.command);
            }
        }
        while (Interpreter.command != "quit" || Interpreter.command != "exit");
    }
}
```

I am using Gentoo Linux and Mono 6.12.0.122

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function error: not all code paths return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496021/function-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: The `runCommand` method signature indicates that it returns a `bool` value, but the method never returns a value.  You'd either need to change the method signature to `void` or return a value.  (Probably the latter, since the consuming code is *expecting* a `bool` value.)

Comment: It worked. Thanks @david